# jQuery Mobile Listview with a header being injected on pagebeforeshow, an action button on the header does not work on listview sub pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, xslt

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and JQM 1.3.0, I am using the following code to render the header and footer on all the pages and subpages in case of listviews :

JavaScript:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.defaultTransition = 'none';
});

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function () { 

    //var ActivePgURL=($.mobile.activePage.attr('url'));

    var hdhtml = $($.mobile.activePage).children('div').eq(0).clone();
    var fthtml = $($.mobile.activePage).children('div').eq(2).clone();
    $('div:jqmData(role="page")').on('pageinit',function() {
        $('div:jqmData(role="header")').remove();
        $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').remove();
        $('div:jqmData(role="page")').prepend(hdhtml).append(fthtml);
    });
    if( $('div:jqmData(role="page")').length >2 ){
        $('div:jqmData(role="header")').remove();
        $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').remove();
        $('div:jqmData(role="page")').prepend(hdhtml).append(fthtml);
    }

    $('#action_menu').change(actionHandler);
});

$(document).ready(function() {      
    var currentUrl = $.mobile.activePage.data('url');

    $("#header-logo").on("click",function(){
        window.location.href=mobileMainViewUrl;
    });

    $('#mainsrpactbtn').change(serpActionHandler);

    //$('#mainsrpactbtn').selectmenu("refresh");

    $('#searh_action').change(searchToolActHndlr);
});

function pageTitle() {

    var activePgTitle=($.mobile.activePage.attr('title'));

    //alert("this is function X"+activePgTitle);
    return activePgTitle;
} 

function  getUrl() {
    var currentUrl = $.mobile.activePage.data('url');         
    alert("this is the page before create function"+currentUrl);
    return currentUrl;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!--These are all my javascript functions I am using, the HTML that renders the the header is as follows -->

<body class="ui-mobile-viewport">

  <div  id="keysearch" data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-url="keysearch" title="Search Results">
    <!-- this is the template that holds the header for the home page  which works as required-->
    <xsl:call-template name="my_page_header"></xsl:call-template>

    <!--I have a control group with two buttons  Refine and parametric the refine is where the problem header is -->
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="display:inline-block;" id="pm_btns">
      <a data-role="button"  data-theme="c" id="refinebutton" class="f_serp_button" onClick="RefineFunction();"><xsl:value-of select="$refinesrch"/></a>
      <a href="#ParametricPage" data-role="button"  data-theme="c"  id="parametrics" class="f_serp_button ui-disabled" ><xsl:value-of select="$prmtrcsrch"/></a>  
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="f_hidden" data-theme="c">
      <select data-native-menu="false" name='searh_action' id='searh_action' data-theme="a" ></select>
    </div>  
    <xsl:call-template name="my_page_footer"/>
  </div><!-- /page -->

  <!-- REFINE -->
  <div data-role="page" id="refine" title="Refine">
    <head>
    </head>
    <xsl:call-template name="refine_page_header"></xsl:call-template>
    <div data-role="content" >

      <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="c" class="f_hidden">
        <select data-native-menu="false" name="mainsrpactbtn" id="mainsrpactbtn" data-theme="a"></select>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

XSLT:

```
<!--This is the code that renders the refine page header-->

<xsl:template name="refine_page_header">
  <!-- *** replace the following with your own xhtml code or replace the text
       between the xsl:text tags with html escaped html code *** -->

  <div data-role="header" id="refine_header">

    <a data-theme="a"  data-role="button" data-icon="check" rel="external" href="/search?{$all_results_url}#keysearch">Done</a>
    <span id="header-logo" ></span>
    <!-- This is the left action button -->
    <!-- This is the left action button -->
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="a"  rel="external" data-icon="f-action" data-iconpos="notext" href="javascript:callSerpActionButton('mainsrpactbtn', getUrl());"></a>
  </div>

</xsl:template>
```

The refine page has a template that renders listviews.  Each subpage gets the header, but the action button does not work. The control is going into the function, but the select menu is not displayed. Any help on  this is much appreciated. I am new to jQuery and JQM. I do not not where the problem is cause the done button works on all the pages.

PS: I have done my research. I am confused as to why my done button works and the other action button that renders the select menu does not.  Listviews create dynamic pages, but if the header is getting created and the function is being called, why is the select menu hidden?